# Painting a lot of diagrams for a board game

Tags: java, android, image, xamarin

I'm creating a chess application and I would like to show plenty of big chess diagrams in scrollview. At the moment I just create ImageView for every diagram, create bitmap into it, paint the diagram on a canvas and that's it.

However, it goes crazy with memory necessary to work. On my quadHD display it uses hundreds of MB even on A4R4G4B4. As I need always to show only a chess board, pieces and arrows, it seems pretty unnecessary to store so much bitmap data as I'm only reusing the same images many times plus painting some polygons. Is there a way to make this more efficiently? Is there a way how to use ImageView without bitmap data, just painting to it when it's on the screen?

```
public void UpdateLecturePreviewPositionsCount(int newCount)
{
    //Function never removes extra views, but adds views if more then previously necessary
    while (lecturePreviewBoards.Count < newCount)
    {
        lecturePreviewBoards.Add(CreateBoard((xScreen - (NUM_DIAGRAMS_PER_PAGE * 2) * DIAGRAM_PADDING) / NUM_DIAGRAMS_PER_PAGE));
        lecturePreviewBoards[lecturePreviewBoards.Count - 1].imgv.SetPadding(DIAGRAM_PADDING, DIAGRAM_PADDING, DIAGRAM_PADDING, DIAGRAM_PADDING);
        layoutLecturePositionsPreview.AddView(lecturePreviewBoards[lecturePreviewBoards.Count - 1].imgv);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < newCount; i++)
        lecturePreviewBoards[i].imgv.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    for (int i = newCount; i < lecturePreviewBoards.Count; i++)
        lecturePreviewBoards[i].imgv.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

}

public c_image_painting CreateBoard(double dblSize = -1)
{
    if (dblSize < 0)
        dblSize = xScreen;
    int size = (int)dblSize;
    c_image_painting cbp = new c_image_painting();
    cbp.bmp = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(size, size, Bitmap.Config.Argb4444);
    cbp.cnv = new Canvas();
    cbp.imgv = new ImageView(context);
    cbp.cnv.SetBitmap(cbp.bmp);
    cbp.imgv.SetImageBitmap(cbp.bmp);
    return cbp;
}

public class c_image_painting
{
    public Canvas cnv;
    public Bitmap bmp;
    public ImageView imgv;
    private Bitmap.Config bmpFormat;
    public c_image_painting()
    {
        bmpFormat=Bitmap.Config.Argb4444;
    }
    public c_image_painting(Bitmap.Config bc)
    {
        bmpFormat = bc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome, but the code to be reviewed here must be shared through your question.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Thank you. What's the reason to post a code in this case please? I highlighted the problem code description to it be easier to read.

Comment: This has been already discussed on meta. [Take a look](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/pastebin-thoughts)

Comment: Ok, you are right, it's easier to have a piece of code to look at, even if the description of problem is precise.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You'll receive better reviews if you show a complete example.  For example, I recommend that you [edit] to show the necessary imports, and a `main()` that shows how to call your function.  It's not mandatory, but it really helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rendering the bitmap in memory, you could define a custom view that takes a `Board` and renders it.

I did this for an Android app for a variant of the Go board game, and it worked pretty well. The basic idea of this [AbstractBoardView](https://github.com/rillig/Phantom-Go-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/de/roland_illig/android/phantomgo/AbstractBoardView.kt) is to have the board state somewhere and to connect it to a view so that it can be drawn.

The memory requirements for this class are exceptionally low, compared to a precomputed bitmap. Even more because my implementation doesn't even hold the board state, it just provides access to it via abstract methods.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, easy to implement and saving huge amount of memory! Thank you.